# Model selection with fixed adjusting group of covariates

Tags: regression, machine-learning, model-selection, lasso, confounding

I am wondering if there exists any method to perform variable selection in the case where you want to adjust for confounding effects (whether or not they are significant).

The setting is the following:

You want to perform a variable selection for a group of variables $X_i , i \in 1...p$ on a variable reponse $Y$ however you know that there is a set of confounding variables $C_i \in 1...c$ .

So you want to know which variable or variables have a true effect on Y within the group of  $X$s (so we want to keep in the model the confounding variables).

$Y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^c \alpha_iC_i + \sum\limits_{j=1}^p \beta_jX_j$

The easiest way is to run a model selection within the residuals of the regression
$\epsilon = Y - \sum\limits_{i=1}^c \alpha'_iC_i $

However, due to the confounding nature of the $C$s we know that $\alpha' \ne \alpha$ so I am afraid to increase the false discovery rate in the set of $X$s. So my question is:

Are there any regression methods that can directly tackle this?

Comment: Is there no reason to include only the candidate covariates of $X$ in the calculation of the $\mathcal{L}_1$ penalty of the lasso?

Comment: I don't know if I well understand your point.

Do you suggest to do that regression:

$argmin  ( ||Y - ( \sum\alpha_i C_i +\sum \beta_p X_p)||_2 + \lambda || \beta||_1 ) $

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.